# How do I remove all circular references from an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

how would I go about removing **all** circular references inside of an object? For example,

```js
let certainObject = { abc: 'test' }
certainObject.prop = certainObject
removeCircular(certainObject)
```

would become

```js
{ abc: 'test' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through the object, while keeping track of which objects you've already seen.

```
function removeCircular(obj) {
    const seen = new Map();
    const recurse = obj => {
        seen.add(obj,true);
        for( let [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            if( typeof v !== "object") continue;
            if(seen.has(v)) delete obj[k];
            else recurse(v);
        }
    }
    recurse(obj);
}
```

Note that this modifies the object in-place. If you want to keep the original object, you'll need to clone it first.

Comment: Just made a small adjustment, because it was iterating leaf nodes and they won't work!

Comment: Ok so I've cloned the object doing `const newObject = { ...obj }` , but I can't seem to figure out where to modify it

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Nice code. But would it not make more sense to put the test for object in front? If it is not an object -> continue. Else if seen -> delete. Else recure.
Of course the outcome will be the same, but feels more logic to me. And perhaps even a bit faster?

Comment: @mous Perhaps. I just threw this together, it can almost certainly be improved. Indeed, checking for object-ness first would make a bit more sense.

Comment: Why do you use a `Map` instead of a `Set`?

Comment: In Chrome I'm getting this error: seen.add is not a function

Comment: const obj = {};
const obj2 = {1: obj, 2: obj} // no any circulars here but code will give false positive right?

Comment: Multiple properties referencing the same object doesn't mean they are circular. { prop1:obj1, prop2: obj1 } gets prop2 deleted for no reason.

Answer (score 2):

I would say something like:

```
function removeCircular(ref) {
    for (let i in ref) {
        if (ref[i] === ref) delete(ref[i]);
        else if (typeof ref[i] == 'Object') removeCircular(ref[i]);
    }
}
```

Or do you want this to work recursively? - edit, it is now recursive. However, this code could potentially end up in a loop. So the code of @NiettheDarkAbsol is better.

However, your example is not circular. You assign this to property, which is effectively the window object. If you want to have a circular object, you have to do:

```
certainObject = { abc: 'test' };
certainObject.propery = certainObject;
```

With such an example, my code works.

Comment: I would probably say recursive, because of the nested objects, etc

Comment: Like I said, it is NOT recursive. But ok, will do...

Comment: Ah, I see how it works now. That's what i had in mind! 

Comment: Well, like I said, it depends a bit on your application. If there is a change that a deeper object links to a parent-object 2 levels back, my code might go in an infinite loop. Then you should choose Niels's code. Mine is simpler, so if you know it will suffice, you might consider it.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding an updated version of Niet's answer that worked for me. And also because I can't comment/reply to Markus Knappen Johansson's question. :-P

The difference is using `seen.set` instead of `seen.add`. I'm guessing that `.add` is from another language?

```
function removeCircular(obj) {
  const seen = new Map();

  const recurse = obj => {
    seen.set(obj, true);

    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      if (typeof v !== 'object') return;
      if (seen.has(v)) delete obj[k];
      else recurse(v);
    });
  };

  recurse(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
            var prams = {
                name: 'abc',
                obj : this,
                val : 'hello ',
               
            }
            

           

            function removecyclic(obj){
               newobj = {};
               for(key in obj){
                    if(typeof obj[key] == 'object'){
                        if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                             newobj[key] = obj[key];
                            
                        }
                       
                        
                    }
                    else{
                        newobj[key] = obj[key];
                    }
                    
                }
                return newobj;
            }

           

           console.log(removecyclic(prams));
```

Comment: How is this removing cycles? hasOwnProperty() does only check if the property is native or custom-added. Does not check for cycles...