# Is there a way to check/prevent setting object property to it's object reference?

Tags: javascript

Imagine situation:

```
const someObject = {a: 'A'};
someObject['b'] = someObject;
```

This will end up having circular dependency.

[image]

Is there are way to run some method/function to check if any properties in object refer to it's parent or parent of parent (imagine having property as an array of objects whose properties refer to any top level parent object)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove all circular references from an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091604/how-do-i-remove-all-circular-references-from-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes, you can easily check by recursively traversing the tree and keeping a set of visited objects. But why would you *want* to prevent this?

Comment: I only found solutions, where it is recursively checked if object repeats in the tree. For example @Justinas suggestion would remove object if it is sibling object (which is not circular reference). const a = {}; const b = {a: a, b: a, c: a, d: {f: a}} is not circular dependency. The reason I am asking is of pure curiosity and a some situation I had in code where object property was referenced to object itself in deep nesting.

Comment: @AndriusOlišauskas Then keep only the ancestors of the current branch in the set of visited objects, by removing them again when the traversal takes you to the next branch.